# Is it bad practice to pass a components scope to a store service - Angular

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Currently this is how I'm subscribing to relevant parts of my state in components:

```
 this.store.pipe(
      select((state: any) => state.data.relevantInfo),
      untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe((relevantInfo: RelevantInfo) => 
        this.doSomethingWithInfo(relevantInfo));
```

`untilDestoryed(this)` is an npm package which automatically unsubscribes when the component is destroyed.

Since I subscribe to the same parts of the state in different components, I was thinking about creating a Store Service, which returns the corresponding observable...

```
  selectRelevantInfo(scope) {
    return this.store.pipe(select((state: State) => state.data.relevantInfo),
      untilDestroyed(scope));
  }
```

...and calling it like this:

```
this.storeService.selectRelevantInfo(this)
  .subscribe((relevantInfo: RelevantInfo) =>                        
      this.doSomethingWithInfo(relevantInfo));
```

Now my question is, would passing the scope this to the StoreService be considered bad practice? Because it probably is - any idea how I could clean up  the subscriptions without following this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `this.storeService.selectRelevantInfo().pipe(untilDestroyed(this)....` instead of doing it in the service. Your services shouldn't be the one handling unsubscribe.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your suggestion!